# AS3 softkeyboard auto slide up

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I am having trouble to have the softkeyboard to auto slide up on iPad.

Here is my code to trigger the softkeyboard, however it doesn't work somehow...

```
this.dispatchEvent(new SoftKeyboardEvent(SoftKeyboardEvent.SOFT_KEYBOARD_ACTIVATING, true, true, null, SoftKeyboardTrigger.CONTENT_TRIGGERED));
```

anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
tf.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
tf.needsSoftKeyboard = true;
tf.addEventListener( FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocus );


private function onFocus( e:FocusEvent ):void {
    tf.requestSoftKeyboard();
}
```

Comment: Thanks San I give it a go.